# Jasperserver Array parameter issue

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a query

```
select * from crm_query where $X{IN,ref_no,ref_no}` in `jasper report
```

The parameter `ref_no` its class is `java.util.Collection`. The report work perfectly in jasper soft report. But not working in`jasper server`.

This is the `url` for connecting `jasper server`

> http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/projects/test_report.pdf?ref_no=31&ref_no=29&ref_no=33

My issues is that `jasper server` getting `NULL` value for the parameter `ref_no`. Why this happening like this? Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Thats a localhost link ..it will open only on your pc. Please check your links before posting.
Also, your query should be

```
select * from crm_query where $X{IN,ref_no,$P{ref_no}}
```

Comment: Yes its localhost. But the parameter value is not receiving in server(localhost).Also i tried to print the parameter in report. But no use,Its not print anything :(

Comment: Have you added the parameter in the input control ?

Comment: Yes.i create new input control `ref_no`. and connected to the report. Its path is `/reports/projects/ref_no`

Comment: Please check the url

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8SBq8Fd16-FQTFUXzM1cC13OEE/view

Comment: Tomcat Server Log files for jasper server.

`127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2017:11:01:51 +0530] "GET /jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/projects/test_report.pdf?ref_no=31&ref_no=29 HTTP/1.1" 200 1383
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2017:11:01:52 +0530] "GET /jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/projects/test_report.pdf?ref_no=31&ref_no=29 HTTP/1.1" 200 1383`

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying
Seems to be a problem with your datatypes..It says you're comparing an integer to a varchar.
also check if your datasource is added correctly.
I don't think I can figure out more than that online.

Comment: no its not the error i just remove the where condition. i tried to view the passed parameter in the report.But its shows nothing.

Comment: Does the nested datatype class of the parameter ref_no with class java.util.Collection match the datatype of the ref_no column?

Comment: Yes..The datatype of ref_no matches

Comment: Hmm...thats all I can think of..sorry. Lets hope someone else can help you

Comment: Malcolm Vaz You there. Now the parameter prints in report. I got another error. I cant use that parameter in `print when expression field` I use this code `<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{ref_no}.contains( $F{query_id} )]]></printWhenExpression>`

Comment: Datatype and example of a value in ${ref_no} and $F{query_id}

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you

Comment: Tell me the datatype/class and an example(value like ref. no.= 102) value for ${ref_no} and $F{query_id}

Comment: `ref_no` datatype `java.util.Collection` its values are `[29,33]`.

`query_id` datatype `integer` values `29,32,33`.`query_id` are query return row values.